# Get rid of updates for Microsoft Chinese IME after it's uninstalled

Tags: windows, windows-update, input-languages, ime

I've installed and then uninstalled Chinese input language in Windows 8.
But I still continue to receive every update for Chinese IME (it happens rather frequently).

How can I get rid of these updates (hiding updates doesn't help because I have to hide every update I receive)?

[image]

Comment: There's a relevant Microsoft KB article here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2723161/zh-cn It's in Chinese though, and the [automatic translation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2723161/en-us) isn't really good.

Comment: Looks like it just suggests to turn on auto update in Windows to update dictionary... At least I've discovered that IME wasn't actually removed, so tried to install/uninstall it again...

Comment: After that "Select updates to install" window was bugged and showed that I have update but I wasn't able to see what update it is. Today it finally showed that invisible update - for Chinese IME =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft tech support answered that it can be fixed only via reinstalling Windows ><